# Can I add a neutral bus bar to this panel?

Tags: electrical-panel

I'm working on a panel already installed. Personally, I believe that the previous installers made a mess of the panel while installing a solar panel system. The panel has 3 extra slots for circuit breakers, but the neutral and the ground bars are now full. I understand I'm not supposed to add an additional neutral bar. What should I do to complete this task?

My panel is a Square D panel.

Comment: Please [edit] to add pictures. Is this a main panel or a sub-panel? If it's a main, you may have grounds taking up spaces in the (bonded) neutral bar(s) that can easily be moved to a new ground bar. Depending on panel labeling, you may also be able to combine 2 or 3 grounds (NOT neutrals) in one hole. And you can get a neutral bar kit, but that is rarely needed. Pictures will help us help you.

Comment: Be sure to include pics of the panel _labels_ so people can read the model number and look up specs.

Comment: In a Square D panel you can put two grounds (same size wire only!) in a single screw. But only 1 neutral per screw. Doubling them this way may give you the space you need.

Comment: Still awaiting pictures. I have to wonder if this is a main and a prior worker set one of the (typically 2 for the Square-D panels I'm familar with - but why I want pictures) up with all the grounds, and made you think it's a ground bar when it's actually one of your two neutral bars....

Comment: Is your panel QO (skinny breakers) or Homeline (fat breakers)?  Also, can you post photos of the panel's innards please?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an additional neutral bus. They are available. These are just like the existing neutral but have insulated standoffs.

If this is the main panel, no isolation is required and you can double the bare copper grounding conductors some panels allow for 3. The white grounded conductors can only have 1 wire under each screw. If you are out of space this is normally what is needed as the panels are made with enough grounding/ grounded point to completely fill the panel so in some cases you need to double up the bare copper grounding conductors.

I used the NEC terms for grounding and grounded to help folks understand that they are different as recognized by code even though they may terminate at the same bus in the panel the grounded conductor is normally a current carrying conductor, with a few exceptions the grounding conductor is not normally a current carrying conductor, clear as mud right.

Comment: I have not found extra neutral bars for Square D panels, only extra ground bars.

Comment: I will provide the proper buss kit listing if you provide a photo of your panel and the listing info. As I said there are enough grounded lugs but there are available isolated buss kits, to me it sounds like you have violated code and have more circuits than the panel is rated for. Even then there are kits not to code but they are out there.

Comment: I'm not the person who asked, but since you offered: I have model: qo132m150 photo here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dV1wI.jpg  - it only has three bars in it, and I'm almost maxed on the left side (it's only OK because there are so many 220 breakers on that side). I could not find a bar to fit in the 4th spot, only grounding bars which are meant to mount on the box, not in the empty spot. (Also: I'm trying to fix any code violations so if you see anything let me know please.)

Comment: @ariel [Snyder buss](https://www.electrical.com/Products/Circuit-Breakers-Schneider-Electric/PK9GTA?utm_campaign=14609950791&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=545071120681&utm_term=&adgroupid=127160210156&gclid=CjwKCAiAprGRBhBgEiwANJEY7EH80iadoDPxlemF-sxfBM50zlGxqGge85sTHMr541AV2IsZhEU9NRoCD-gQAvD_BwE) /[Snyder insulator](https://www.gordonelectricsupply.com/p/Square-D-Pkgtab-Load-Center-Ground-Bar-Kit-Qo-Hom/16500?text=16500&gclid=CjwKCAiAprGRBhBgEiwANJEY7Mad48MewDeXhsFpxp5qvwWJ-pEjICXqHy0N6p6BkRQeUQjv8OEdvBoCzFkQAvD_BwE)  And last lugs QO1150AN , but first start with doubling bare

Comment: @Ariel -- Look for a QONKx (1-4) -- these are the neutral kits for QO panels

Comment: Lots of different ways to find the pieces you can build them with individual pieces or complete kits my list above gave 2 of 3 links because that was the max characters .

Answer (score 1):

For Square D Homeline/QO panels for a neutral bar you order a ground bar insulating kit PKGTAB and a ground bar PKxxGTAL (xx replaced with number of terminals i.e. PK23GTAL). You may also need a large adapter lug LK225AN for a jumper to the existing neutral bar.

These or alternative part numbers should be on the panel door sticker.

Answer (score 1):

Every panel manufacturer provides enough neutral spaces for the entire panel to be full of 120V circuits. And they usually provide something for grounds - either a provided accessory ground bar, or some extra spaces on the neutral bar which will be enough if you double/triple up the grounds per panel instructions.

Ground bars are easy retrofits, and every maker offers accessory ground bar kits in the $4 to $8 range.   You see where accessory ground bars are casually added using "screws into the chassis" or a #6 jumper wire for grounding.That's because *ground* carries current only during fault conditions.  Neutral carries *normal service current* all the time - and must be thermally rated for the worst-case scenario. So accessory neutral bars are not so simple.

If it seems like you're out of neutral bar spaces, look at several things.

- Are you packing the grounds as much as allowed?  Code requires only 1 neutral per terminal. However, 2 or 3 ground wires are allowed per terminal, depending on what UL has approved for the panel. Check the panel labeling, and dense-pack the grounds as much as you can.  Typically, panel makers give you enough neutral spaces for grounds *if* you max-pack them.
- Can you use an *accessory* ground bar? This is much more workable than an accessory neutral bar, since it doesn't need to carry normal service current.  Moving grounds to a ground bar will almost always free up enough neutral space. Note that the double/triple-pack rules on *accessory bars* are different - at least one panel allows 3 on the neutral bar but only 2 on accessory ground bars.
- Are you over-stuffing the panel?  The manufacturer built the panel to only have so many *circuits*, allowing for the number of tandem breakers approved for the panel (e.g. 30/40, or 30-space 40-circuit, meaning 10 spaces for tandems).  It's possible to blow right past that limit using "non-CTL" tandem breakers, which defeat the reject feature which keeps you from overstuffing the panel.  The CTL (Circuit Total Limitation) rules have been abolished, but it's a matter of debate whether you're now allowed to stuff existing panels beyond their label limit.  The UL approved labeling, which you must follow, clearly says "no", but check with your panel manufacturer to see if they got a waiver from UL, and ask for a copy of that letter.